# How to tag/mention a user after some time?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have a timer command where you put in the time you want in seconds and then you wait. But I want it so that when it's done it tags you but I don't know how.

```
[Command("timer")]
[Summary("**%timer** + time in seconds and then it will tell you when it's done!")]
private async Task test(string input)
{   
    //something like this
    User user = Context.User;

    string name = Context.User.Username;
    Int32 time = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    time *= 1000;
    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":stopwatch: **" + name + "** has put a timer on **" + input + "** seconds! :stopwatch:");
    await Task.Delay(time);
    //and then
    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":stopwatch: **" + user + "'s** timer on **" + input + "** seconds is done! :stopwatch:");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the runmode of the command to async :

```
[Command("timer", RunMode = RunMode.Async)] // <-- here
[Summary("**%timer** + time in seconds and then it will tell you when it's done!")]
private async Task test(string input)
{   
    Int32 time = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    time *= 1000;

    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":stopwatch: **" + Context.User.Mention + "** has put a timer on **" + input + "** seconds! :stopwatch:");

    await Task.Delay(time);

    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":stopwatch: **" + Context.User.Mention + "'s** timer on **" + input + "** seconds is done! :stopwatch:");
}
```

Comment: Sorry this did not answer my question :/ What I am trying to ask for is how to mention the user and under "//something like this" I meant if there was something like that I could do to mention the user.

Comment: Oh, you can use the `Mention` property. I've updated the answer.